# How to connect and re-use an already opened browser window in Protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriverjs

In general, the protractor scripts are executed in a new browser instance with the following capabilities

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'firefox'
}
```

Is there any snippets or ways to tweak this; so that our scripts make use of an already opened browser through protractor.

Comment: you meant, you just want to open a browser one time and use it for executing all scripts?

Comment: @SureshSalloju I open a browser, quits the driver; again I want the same browser to execute my other test.

Comment: use  beforeAll()- for browser opening and afterAll() - for quit the driver

Comment: No, I want to re-use the existing browser; how to achieve it.

Comment: then don't the driver  quit man

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, for **angular2**:

1. Go to [WebDriverHub](http://localhost:4444/wd/hub) and click on *Create Session*, copy the generated id (eg: `2919ed90-efac-48ee-83df-46f8e98ebce7`), you'll need it in step#2.
2. Add/Modify `protractor.conf.js` to reflect the following.

   exports.config.seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   exports.config.seleniumSessionId: '2919ed90-efac-48ee-83df-46f8e98ebce7',
   exports.config.directConnect: false

**Observe:**

- Setting `directConnect` to **false** is important.
- `seleniumSessionId` will need to be updated everytime u create new session (wish there was a way to tell, *use current running browser window* without updating `seleniumSessionId` everytime)

Answer (score 0):

On this line you have an example on how it's passed on the command line to Protractor: https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/3f3805f9496fb130ae01b3e3278ee1ea7684d8e7#diff-b61b72dbab31e232fdb8466ebf733c4dR54
You can use the same parameter in your config to pass the current session ID.
You can usually get the current sessionId by `browser.getSessionId`
Example 1:

```
var runProtractor = spawn('bin/protractor',
     ['spec/attachSession.js', '--seleniumSessionId=' + currentSessionId]);
```

Example 2 using your config:

```
var checkOptions = {
     hostname: 'localhost',
     port: 4444,
     seleniumSessionId: yourCurrentSessionId
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **browser.getCapabilities()** to get the *debugger address*.
Using the debugger address we can communicate with the existing browser.
In the below link I've written an article on this, take a look into this.

[Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/protractor-run-test-existing-automated-browser-koushik-chatterjee)